# PowerShell script module doesn't return any info

Tags: powershell

I have the following module:

```
Function Get-ProcessHash {
    param($ComputerName)

    $username = $ComputerName + '\localadm'
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'supersecret' -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $cred -Authentication Negotiate -ScriptBlock {
        Get-Process * | Select-Object Id, Name, ProductVersion, Company, Path, @{l="SHA256";e={if ($_.Path -ne $null) { (Get-FileHash $_.Path).Hash}}}
    }
}
```

This script module is located at `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SuperModule\SuperModule.psm1`. I can see its functions via `Get-Command -Module SuperModule`. If I run the content of the script manually, outside of the function, it will work and return all the values, but when I try to run the function as `PS C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Scripts> Get-ProcessHash US0001` it doesn't return a thing.

The credentials are valid, I can execute the script outside of the module and it works.

Comment: Have you been making changes to this module while it was loaded? If you close all active PowerShell sessions and try again is your issue the same?

Comment: Good point @Matt, could also try `Import-Module -Force`

Comment: I usually try to follow KISS in comments.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it was exactly that. Please post your comment as answer so I can mark this question as complete :D

Comment: @JChris: If Matt doesn't get around to posting an answer, you can [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As Matt said in the comments, the solution was simple:

"Have you been making changes to this module while it was loaded? If you close all active PowerShell sessions and try again is your issue the same?"